# Modified QuickContactBadge, Error inflating class below Android 5.0

Tags: android, overlay, nosuchmethoderror, quickcontactbadge

I have modified quick contact badge to get rid of the overlay. It works perfectly in Lollipop. But for some weird reason it throws a myriad of different errors when used below Lollipop. Why? And how can I fix it so it works below 5.0? Also is there a better way to remove the overlay?

Here's the modified QuickContactBadge class, the only modification I made was removing the method that created the overlay (the little arrow on the bottom right)

```
import android.content.AsyncQueryHandler;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.QuickContact;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Widget used to show an image with the standard QuickContact badge and
 * on-click behavior.
 */
public class QuickContactBadge extends ImageView implements OnClickListener {
    private Uri mContactUri;
    private String mContactEmail;
    private String mContactPhone;
    private QueryHandler mQueryHandler;
    private Drawable mDefaultAvatar;
    private Bundle mExtras = null;
    private Context mContext = getContext();
    protected String[] mExcludeMimes = null;
    static final private int TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP = 0;
    static final private int TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP = 1;
    static final private int TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER = 2;
    static final private int TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER = 3;
    static final private String EXTRA_URI_CONTENT = "uri_content";
    static final String[] EMAIL_LOOKUP_PROJECTION = new String[] {
            RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, };
    static final int EMAIL_ID_COLUMN_INDEX = 0;
    static final int EMAIL_LOOKUP_STRING_COLUMN_INDEX = 1;
    static final String[] PHONE_LOOKUP_PROJECTION = new String[] {
            PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY, };
    static final int PHONE_ID_COLUMN_INDEX = 0;
    static final int PHONE_LOOKUP_STRING_COLUMN_INDEX = 1;

    public QuickContactBadge(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public QuickContactBadge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public QuickContactBadge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyleAttr) {
        this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
    }

    public QuickContactBadge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        TypedArray styledAttributes = mContext
                .obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Theme);

        styledAttributes.recycle();
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            mQueryHandler = new QueryHandler(mContext.getContentResolver());
        }
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    /** This call has no effect anymore, as there is only one QuickContact mode */
    /** True if a contact, an email address or a phone number has been assigned */
    private boolean isAssigned() {
        return mContactUri != null || mContactEmail != null
                || mContactPhone != null;
    }

    /**
     * Resets the contact photo to the default state.
     */
    public void setImageToDefault() {
        if (mDefaultAvatar == null) {
            mDefaultAvatar = mContext
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
        }
        setImageDrawable(mDefaultAvatar);
    }

    /**
     * Assign the contact uri that this QuickContactBadge should be associated
     * with. Note that this is only used for displaying the QuickContact window
     * and won't bind the contact's photo for you. Call
     * {@link #setImageDrawable(Drawable)} to set the photo.
     *
     * @param contactUri
     *            Either a {@link Contacts#CONTENT_URI} or
     *            {@link Contacts#CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI} style URI.
     */
    public void assignContactUri(Uri contactUri) {
        mContactUri = contactUri;
        mContactEmail = null;
        mContactPhone = null;
        onContactUriChanged();
    }

    /**
     * Assign a contact based on an email address. This should only be used when
     * the contact's URI is not available, as an extra query will have to be
     * performed to lookup the URI based on the email.
     *
     * @param emailAddress
     *            The email address of the contact.
     * @param lazyLookup
     *            If this is true, the lookup query will not be performed until
     *            this view is clicked.
     */
    public void assignContactFromEmail(String emailAddress, boolean lazyLookup) {
        assignContactFromEmail(emailAddress, lazyLookup, null);
    }

    /**
     * Assign a contact based on an email address. This should only be used when
     * the contact's URI is not available, as an extra query will have to be
     * performed to lookup the URI based on the email.
     * 
     * @param emailAddress
     *            The email address of the contact.
     * @param lazyLookup
     *            If this is true, the lookup query will not be performed until
     *            this view is clicked.
     * @param extras
     *            A bundle of extras to populate the contact edit page with if
     *            the contact is not found and the user chooses to add the email
     *            address to an existing contact or create a new contact. Uses
     *            the same string constants as those found in
     *            {@link android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents.Insert}
     */
    public void assignContactFromEmail(String emailAddress, boolean lazyLookup,
            Bundle extras) {
        mContactEmail = emailAddress;
        mExtras = extras;
        if (!lazyLookup && mQueryHandler != null) {
            mQueryHandler.startQuery(
                    TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP,
                    null,
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(Email.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI,
                            Uri.encode(mContactEmail)),
                    EMAIL_LOOKUP_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        } else {
            mContactUri = null;
            onContactUriChanged();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Assign a contact based on a phone number. This should only be used when
     * the contact's URI is not available, as an extra query will have to be
     * performed to lookup the URI based on the phone number.
     *
     * @param phoneNumber
     *            The phone number of the contact.
     * @param lazyLookup
     *            If this is true, the lookup query will not be performed until
     *            this view is clicked.
     */
    public void assignContactFromPhone(String phoneNumber, boolean lazyLookup) {
        assignContactFromPhone(phoneNumber, lazyLookup, new Bundle());
    }

    /**
     * Assign a contact based on a phone number. This should only be used when
     * the contact's URI is not available, as an extra query will have to be
     * performed to lookup the URI based on the phone number.
     *
     * @param phoneNumber
     *            The phone number of the contact.
     * @param lazyLookup
     *            If this is true, the lookup query will not be performed until
     *            this view is clicked.
     * @param extras
     *            A bundle of extras to populate the contact edit page with if
     *            the contact is not found and the user chooses to add the phone
     *            number to an existing contact or create a new contact. Uses
     *            the same string constants as those found in
     *            {@link android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents.Insert}
     */
    public void assignContactFromPhone(String phoneNumber, boolean lazyLookup,
            Bundle extras) {
        mContactPhone = phoneNumber;
        mExtras = extras;
        if (!lazyLookup && mQueryHandler != null) {
            mQueryHandler.startQuery(TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP, null, Uri
                    .withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                            mContactPhone), PHONE_LOOKUP_PROJECTION, null,
                    null, null);
        } else {
            mContactUri = null;
            onContactUriChanged();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Assigns the drawable that is to be drawn on top of the assigned contact
     * photo.
     *
     * @param overlay
     *            Drawable to be drawn over the assigned contact photo. Must
     *            have a non-zero instrinsic width and height.
     */

    private void onContactUriChanged() {
        setEnabled(isAssigned());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // If contact has been assigned, mExtras should no longer be null, but
        // do a null check
        // anyway just in case assignContactFromPhone or Email was called with a
        // null bundle or
        // wasn't assigned previously.
        final Bundle extras = (mExtras == null) ? new Bundle() : mExtras;
        if (mContactUri != null) {
            QuickContact.showQuickContact(getContext(), QuickContactBadge.this,
                    mContactUri, QuickContact.MODE_LARGE, mExcludeMimes);
        } else if (mContactEmail != null && mQueryHandler != null) {
            extras.putString(EXTRA_URI_CONTENT, mContactEmail);
            mQueryHandler.startQuery(
                    TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER,
                    extras,
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(Email.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI,
                            Uri.encode(mContactEmail)),
                    EMAIL_LOOKUP_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        } else if (mContactPhone != null && mQueryHandler != null) {
            extras.putString(EXTRA_URI_CONTENT, mContactPhone);
            mQueryHandler.startQuery(TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER, extras,
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                            mContactPhone), PHONE_LOOKUP_PROJECTION, null,
                    null, null);
        } else {
            // If a contact hasn't been assigned, don't react to click.
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(event);
        event.setClassName(QuickContactBadge.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info);
        info.setClassName(QuickContactBadge.class.getName());
    }

    /**
     * Set a list of specific MIME-types to exclude and not display. For
     * example, this can be used to hide the {@link Contacts#CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}
     * profile icon.
     */
    public void setExcludeMimes(String[] excludeMimes) {
        mExcludeMimes = excludeMimes;
    }

    private class QueryHandler extends AsyncQueryHandler {
        public QueryHandler(ContentResolver cr) {
            super(cr);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onQueryComplete(int token, Object cookie, Cursor cursor) {
            Uri lookupUri = null;
            Uri createUri = null;
            boolean trigger = false;
            Bundle extras = (cookie != null) ? (Bundle) cookie : new Bundle();
            try {
                switch (token) {
                case TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER:
                    trigger = true;
                    createUri = Uri.fromParts("tel",
                            extras.getString(EXTRA_URI_CONTENT), null);
                    //$FALL-THROUGH$
                case TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP: {
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        long contactId = cursor.getLong(PHONE_ID_COLUMN_INDEX);
                        String lookupKey = cursor
                                .getString(PHONE_LOOKUP_STRING_COLUMN_INDEX);
                        lookupUri = Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER:
                    trigger = true;
                    createUri = Uri.fromParts("mailto",
                            extras.getString(EXTRA_URI_CONTENT), null);
                    //$FALL-THROUGH$
                case TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP: {
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        long contactId = cursor.getLong(EMAIL_ID_COLUMN_INDEX);
                        String lookupKey = cursor
                                .getString(EMAIL_LOOKUP_STRING_COLUMN_INDEX);
                        lookupUri = Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
            mContactUri = lookupUri;
            onContactUriChanged();
            if (trigger && lookupUri != null) {
                // Found contact, so trigger QuickContact
                QuickContact.showQuickContact(getContext(),
                        QuickContactBadge.this, lookupUri,
                        QuickContact.MODE_LARGE, mExcludeMimes);
            } else if (createUri != null) {
                // Prompt user to add this person to contacts
                final Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT, createUri);
                if (extras != null) {
                    extras.remove(EXTRA_URI_CONTENT);
                    intent.putExtras(extras);
                }
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error it would throw

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class com.bernard.beaconportal.activities.QuickContactBadge
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at com.bernard.beaconportal.activities.fragment.MessageListFragment$MessageListAdapter.newView(MessageListFragment.java:1941)
at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:250)
at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:230)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2765)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1811)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1627)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2586)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:890)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:459)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2361)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2074)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1256)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6658)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.ImageView.<init>
at com.bernard.beaconportal.activities.QuickContactBadge.<init>(QuickContactBadge.java:84)
at com.bernard.beaconportal.activities.QuickContactBadge.<init>(QuickContactBadge.java:79)
at com.bernard.beaconportal.activities.QuickContactBadge.<init>(QuickContactBadge.java:74)
... 70 more
```

Error points here

```
 <com.bernard.beaconportal.activities.QuickContactBadge
        android:id="@+id/contact_badge"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture" />
```

Comment: Your exception and your issue title do not match. Updating.

Comment: Well the root of the error was nosuchmethod, but I see your logic

Comment: Why not extend `QuickContactBadge` instead of copying the source? Is the `QuickContactBadge` class located in `com.bernard.beaconportal.activities`?

Comment: @Jared Burrows com.bernard.beaconportal is in my app, so I copied the source code to my app. I'm familiar with editing a method by extending the android source, but how do you remove a method? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I suggested extending because parts of the class may have changed based on the API level. What do you mean remove a method?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I simply deleted the method that created the overlay from the source code in order to remove the overlay from the quick contact badge. But I guess I could just make the method blank. Is there any good examples you recommend I look at?

Comment: I do not know of any examples. Before doing anything else, just try extending `QuickContactBadge` and then modifying. See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/QuickContactBadge.html. There are different API levels. This may be causing an issue.

Comment: @JaredBurrows thanks I did what you said, but instead just modified my original code by removing all methods that use something above api14. Thanks for the help

Comment: Would you mine if I made an answer?

Comment: @JaredBurrows of course not, go for it

Comment: Thanks. I added an answer to some up our discussion. Feel free to add more(comment and I can add).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP has posted his *fixed* source code for solving his original problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29438808/950427.

Most of his issue was worked out in the comments, here is a summary.

Two ways of solving this issue when creating your *own* custom views from Android's source.:

**1. Copy and Pasting:**

You need to make sure none of the methods in the source code are **above** your **minSdkVersion**. OP was able to check the docs here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/QuickContactBadge.html.

OP's code(not mine):

> Here's the fixed code that should work in all android versions
>   starting from api 14 and above. I just took out all methods that
>   require anything above api 14.

```
import android.content.AsyncQueryHandler;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.QuickContact;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Widget used to show an image with the standard QuickContact badge
 * and on-click behavior.
 */
public class OverlayLessQuickContactBadge extends ImageView implements OnClickListener {
    private Uri mContactUri;
    private String mContactEmail;
    private String mContactPhone;
    private Drawable mOverlay;
    private QueryHandler mQueryHandler;
    private Drawable mDefaultAvatar;
    private Context mContext = getContext();

    protected String[] mExcludeMimes = null;

    static final private int TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP = 0;
    static final private int TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP = 1;
    static final private int TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER = 2;
    static final private int TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER = 3;

    static final String[] EMAIL_LOOKUP_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        RawContacts.CONTACT_ID,
        Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
    };
    static final int EMAIL_ID_COLUMN_INDEX = 0;
    static final int EMAIL_LOOKUP_STRING_COLUMN_INDEX = 1;

    static final String[] PHONE_LOOKUP_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        PhoneLookup._ID,
        PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY,
    };
    static final int PHONE_ID_COLUMN_INDEX = 0;
    static final int PHONE_LOOKUP_STRING_COLUMN_INDEX = 1;

    public OverlayLessQuickContactBadge(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public OverlayLessQuickContactBadge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public OverlayLessQuickContactBadge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray styledAttributes = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Theme);


        mQueryHandler = new QueryHandler(mContext.getContentResolver());
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    /** This call has no effect anymore, as there is only one QuickContact mode */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setMode(int size) {
    }



    /** True if a contact, an email address or a phone number has been assigned */
    private boolean isAssigned() {
        return mContactUri != null || mContactEmail != null || mContactPhone != null;
    }

    /**
     * Resets the contact photo to the default state.
     */
    public void setImageToDefault() {
        if (mDefaultAvatar == null) {
            mDefaultAvatar = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
        }
        setImageDrawable(mDefaultAvatar);
    }

    /**
     * Assign the contact uri that this QuickContactBadge should be associated
     * with. Note that this is only used for displaying the QuickContact window and
     * won't bind the contact's photo for you. Call {@link #setImageDrawable(Drawable)} to set the
     * photo.
     *
     * @param contactUri Either a {@link Contacts#CONTENT_URI} or
     *            {@link Contacts#CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI} style URI.
     */
    public void assignContactUri(Uri contactUri) {
        mContactUri = contactUri;
        mContactEmail = null;
        mContactPhone = null;
        onContactUriChanged();
    }

    /**
     * Assign a contact based on an email address. This should only be used when
     * the contact's URI is not available, as an extra query will have to be
     * performed to lookup the URI based on the email.
     *
     * @param emailAddress The email address of the contact.
     * @param lazyLookup If this is true, the lookup query will not be performed
     * until this view is clicked.
     */
    public void assignContactFromEmail(String emailAddress, boolean lazyLookup) {
        mContactEmail = emailAddress;
        if (!lazyLookup) {
            mQueryHandler.startQuery(TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP, null,
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(Email.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, Uri.encode(mContactEmail)),
                    EMAIL_LOOKUP_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        } else {
            mContactUri = null;
            onContactUriChanged();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Assign a contact based on a phone number. This should only be used when
     * the contact's URI is not available, as an extra query will have to be
     * performed to lookup the URI based on the phone number.
     *
     * @param phoneNumber The phone number of the contact.
     * @param lazyLookup If this is true, the lookup query will not be performed
     * until this view is clicked.
     */
    public void assignContactFromPhone(String phoneNumber, boolean lazyLookup) {
        mContactPhone = phoneNumber;
        if (!lazyLookup) {
            mQueryHandler.startQuery(TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP, null,
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, mContactPhone),
                    PHONE_LOOKUP_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        } else {
            mContactUri = null;
            onContactUriChanged();
        }
    }

    private void onContactUriChanged() {
        setEnabled(isAssigned());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mContactUri != null) {
            QuickContact.showQuickContact(getContext(), OverlayLessQuickContactBadge.this, mContactUri,
                    QuickContact.MODE_LARGE, mExcludeMimes);
        } else if (mContactEmail != null) {
            mQueryHandler.startQuery(TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER, mContactEmail,
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(Email.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, Uri.encode(mContactEmail)),
                    EMAIL_LOOKUP_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        } else if (mContactPhone != null) {
            mQueryHandler.startQuery(TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER, mContactPhone,
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, mContactPhone),
                    PHONE_LOOKUP_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        } else {
            // If a contact hasn't been assigned, don't react to click.
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set a list of specific MIME-types to exclude and not display. For
     * example, this can be used to hide the {@link Contacts#CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}
     * profile icon.
     */
    public void setExcludeMimes(String[] excludeMimes) {
        mExcludeMimes = excludeMimes;
    }

    private class QueryHandler extends AsyncQueryHandler {

        public QueryHandler(ContentResolver cr) {
            super(cr);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onQueryComplete(int token, Object cookie, Cursor cursor) {
            Uri lookupUri = null;
            Uri createUri = null;
            boolean trigger = false;

            try {
                switch(token) {
                    case TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER:
                        trigger = true;
                        createUri = Uri.fromParts("tel", (String)cookie, null);

                        //$FALL-THROUGH$
                    case TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP: {
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            long contactId = cursor.getLong(PHONE_ID_COLUMN_INDEX);
                            String lookupKey = cursor.getString(PHONE_LOOKUP_STRING_COLUMN_INDEX);
                            lookupUri = Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey);
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    case TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER:
                        trigger = true;
                        createUri = Uri.fromParts("mailto", (String)cookie, null);

                        //$FALL-THROUGH$
                    case TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP: {
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            long contactId = cursor.getLong(EMAIL_ID_COLUMN_INDEX);
                            String lookupKey = cursor.getString(EMAIL_LOOKUP_STRING_COLUMN_INDEX);
                            lookupUri = Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }

            mContactUri = lookupUri;
            onContactUriChanged();

            if (trigger && lookupUri != null) {
                // Found contact, so trigger QuickContact
                QuickContact.showQuickContact(getContext(), OverlayLessQuickContactBadge.this, lookupUri,
                        QuickContact.MODE_LARGE, mExcludeMimes);
            } else if (createUri != null) {
                // Prompt user to add this person to contacts
                final Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT, createUri);
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Extending the View:**

If you do not want to copy and paste the source, you can simply extend the class and edit the methods you need, but once again make sure you are using the correct methods that are not about your **mindSdkVersion**.

Comment: Looks good, take my code that I put in my answer and put it under the "copy and pasting" section of your answer. That way we can have all the information into one answer.

Comment: I have merged the answers. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Perfect, I'm going to delete my answer and mark yours as right. Thanks for everything.